# Calculating an average of two ints and converting to a double in java (coursework)

Tags: java, int, double

I am learning how to use Java and for my coursework I have been asked to construct an application that will read in the exam mark and coursework mark and then print out to 1 decimal place the average of the coursework and exam mark. When I submit it it says it's incorrect, does anyone have any idea why?

```
{
    int ExamMark=71;                
    int CourseworkMark=40;

    double mark = (double)(ExamMark + CourseworkMark) / 2; 

    System.out.printf("ex = " + ExamMark + " cw = " + CourseworkMark + " mark = " + mark); 
    System.out.println();

  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You forgot the "then print out to **1 decimal** place" part

Comment: Is this code in a class -> main method?

Comment: Yes, it's in a class main method.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are clear about using `System.out.printf` and `System.out.println`

```
System.out.printf("ex =  %d  cw = %d mark = %.2f",ExamMark,CourseworkMark,mark); //System.out.printf

System.out.println("ex = " + ExamMark + " cw = " + CourseworkMark + " mark = " + mark); //System.out.println
```

javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html